# Android Listview item selection

Tags: android

In the adapter class of Listview i have added setOnClickListener event for each of the list items. But whenever we taps on List items, the items are not getting highlighted. 
If i remove setOnClickListener event, i will be able to see the List item selection easily..
Pls tell me, how to fix the problem

in getview of the listAdapter if i add this part, listview item selection color will not come

```
holder.ContactNumber.setText(fitems.get(position).getContactName());

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        setSelectedItem(i);
                         Intent intent = 
                              new Intent(context, preview_screen.class);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: add relevant code here please.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0, i have added snippet of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a selector for your list view item row_selector.xml in re/drawable folder add this selector as your background for you listview_item.xml
This is the default selector used by android you can make a custom one:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Use OnItemClickListener() callback to handle click events on listview items

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for reply. My doubt is if i add SetonClickListner event in adapter class, i am able to select the items but the default selection color will not come.. why?

Comment: @LLL if you want to get the default selctor color you have to use setOnItemClickListener!!

Comment: thanks, i didnt get ur comment... if i add setOnItemClickListener, i wont get default selector, to overcome what i should do?

Comment: @LLL you don't have to handle clicks for your items with registering OnClick Listener on your holder pattern!! Android API provide a call back called OnItemClickListener to handle clicks on listview item

Answer (score 1):

You have to set background for row with xml file...

[See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

**drawable->bg_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. My doubt is if i add SetonClickListner event in adapter class, i am able to select the items but the default selection color will not come.. why?

Answer (score 1):

```
 // ListView Item Click Listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                   // ListView Clicked item index
                   int itemPosition     = position;

                   // ListView Clicked item value
                   String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Show Alert 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();

                  }

             });
```

In list view listener you use that [example](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of giving convertView an onClickListener is not how ListView is working.
Don't set this listener. Instead, set an onItemClickListener or an onItemSelectListener (depends on what you want to do) to the listview and put the code in there.

Comment: Both events are not available in Convertview obj